# Query Get Last Month Data (calculated from now) and parse Json to get item inside Json

Tags: mysql, sql, json, database, database-design

I have two table that related like these:

master_ticket:

```
t_m_id     t_open       t_closed
==================================
111      2018-12-01     2018-12-05
222      2018-12-02     2018-12-06 
333      2018-12-03     2018-12-07
444      2018-12-04     2018-12-08
```

master_data:

```
m_id     m_reference
=====================================
111    {"id": "01","name": "Bahary"}
222    {"id": "02","name": "Mail"}
333    {"id": "03","name": "Ivan"}
444    {"id": "04","name": "Scheil"}
```

How im supposed to do, to make my table looks like this (with filter get last month data from t_open):

```
id   name      t_open     t_closed
===============================
01   Bahary   2018-12-01  2018-12-05
02   Mail     2018-12-02  2018-12-06
03   Ivan     2018-12-03  2018-12-07
04   Scheil   2018-12-04  2018-12-08
```

Please help me guys .... Thanks,

Comment: You want XXXX-XX-X  as your expected output for dates ?

Comment: yupps, and name @Avi

Comment: please write your result clear ! what is x ?!!!

Comment: What version of MySQL?  Newer versions allow 'easy' access into JSON columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may give your expected output.

```
  with cte as (
 select 111 as t_m_id,       '2018-12-01' as t_open,     '2018-12-05' as t_closed 
 union all 
 select 222 as t_m_id,       '2018-12-02' as t_open,     '2018-12-06' as t_closed 
 union all 
 select 333 as t_m_id,       '2018-12-03' as t_open,     '2018-12-07' as t_closed 
 union all 
 select 444 as t_m_id,       '2018-12-04' as t_open,     '2018-12-08' as t_closed) , 
 cte2 as (      

 select 111 as m_id,    '{"id": "01","name": "Bahary"}' as m_reference union all 
 select 222 as m_id,    '{"id": "02","name": "Mail"}' as m_reference union all 
 select 333 as m_id,    '{"id": "03","name": "Ivan"}' as m_reference union all 
 select 444 as m_id,    '{"id": "04","name": "Scheil"}' as m_reference)

  select json_unquote(json_extract(m_reference, '$.id')) as ID, c.t_open, t_closed,
  json_unquote(json_extract(m_reference, '$.name')) AS name from cte   c 
  join cte2 c2 on c.t_m_id = c2.m_id;
```

Output:

```
ID, t_open,     t_closed,   name
01, 2018-12-01, 2018-12-05, Bahary 
02, 2018-12-02, 2018-12-06, Mail
03, 2018-12-03, 2018-12-07, Ivan
04, 2018-12-04, 2018-12-08, Scheil
```